# Android Draw Circle with Different Text

Tags: android, canvas

My application draws a circle when the screen is pressed. I'm trying to put text on the circles according to how many there are the screen. So if your first tap will give you a circle with the text C0, the second will give you a circle for C1, etc.

Currently my code looks like

```
lPaint = new Paint();
lPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
lPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
lPaint.setTextSize(40);

nCanvas.drawCircle(v.x, v.y, 55, cPaint);
nCanvas.drawText("C"+i, v.x, v.y, lPaint);
```

Where v.x and v.y are the coordinators where you've touched the screen, and i is the circle counter. This code starts off just fine, but after the first circle draw, it changes ALL the text for ALL the circles to the new i value. How do I get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new variable i, inside custom view. Then increment variable i inside on click and in onDraw method just draw circle, or whatever you want.For example:

```
package yourpackage.

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Color view used for picking color for drawing
 */
public class ColorView extends View {

    private Paint drawPaint;
    private int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.black);
    private int i;


    public ColorView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ColorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ColorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ColorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setColor(color);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 200, drawPaint);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        drawPaint.setColor(color);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void onClick() {
        i++;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
```